# Qual é o antónimo de «póstumo»?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Normalmente nós não precisamos de um antónimo de *póstumo*. Quando alguém nos fala do filho ou livro de fulano, nós entendemos por omissão que o fulano teve o filho e publicou o livro quando era ainda vivo. Mas imaginemos o seguinte diálogo:

> Cliente: «Bom dia, procuro aquele livro de Machado de Assis, as *Memórias de Brás Cubas*.
>
> Livreiro: «Bom dia, quer dizer as *Memórias **Póstumas** de Brás Cubas*?
>
> Cliente: «Isso, até porque, creio, não existem quaisquer *Memórias __________ de Brás Cubas*.

Qual seria um bom antónimo de *póstumo* para preencher o espaço?

[Tenho a pergunta paralela no SE English Language & Usage.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298547/antonym-for-posthumous)

Comment: «Contemporâneas» quase dava.

Comment: @ANeves Anda lá perto. Não sei se não servirá.

Comment: Como é de qualquer forma uma brincadeira, eu diria "até por que não existem as memórias 'prétumas' de Brás Cubas"...

Comment: @Luis E que tal *ântumas*. Já houve quem usasse, em português, e os franceses já usam *anthume* há muito tempo. Até porque, no latim, o ***t*** de *póstumo* é de *pos**t***. Ao substituíres *post* por *pre*, o ***t*** vai-se. Mesmo sendo brincadeira, há que primar pelo rigor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**«Em vida»**:

> *par=ext18785-clt-96a-2*: Que peso deve ter uma vontade expressa pelo doente **em vida**, por vezes anos antes ?
>   *par=ext35432-soc-95a-2*: Outros casos há mesmo entre nós -- Almada, por exemplo, deu em vida o nome de Romeu Correia a uma rua --, mas são excepções .

Algum contexto para a segunda: os topónimos são geralmente atribuídos postumamente.

Nestes exemplos, *em vida* tem valor de advérbio. Mas também podemos encontrar exemplos como locução adjetiva:

> *par=ext444243-clt-soc-95b-1*: A consagração **em vida** de um dos últimos «monstros sagrados» do jazz é coisa rara.
>   *par=ext743784-soc-95b-1*: Um distinção **em vida** que a autarquia concedeu ainda ao industrial local Joaquim Moreira Pinto e ao médico Manuel Campos Pereira.

Comment: Tou a pensar se «em vida» é realmente um antónimo de «póstumo» ou só de «postumamente». «Memórias em vida de Brás Cubas» não me soa lá muito bem. E nos exemplos que encontraste, teria que ser «vontade expressa *postumamente*» e «deu *postumamente*».

Comment: @Jacinto Adicionei mais uns exemplos que talvez te sosseguem.

Comment: @Artefacto, que tipo de referência é esta: _par=ext18785-clt-96a-2_?

Comment: @felipe.zkn É a entrada do CETEMPúblico. Neste caso alguma coisa na secção de cultura de uma edição de 96.

Comment: @Artefacto, obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: Aceitei a resposta relutantemente. *Memórias em vida* continua a não me soar bem. Tal como, «conheci finalmente o filho em vida do João». Com *consagração, reconhecimento*, etc. já me soa melhor. Talvez por poderem ser mentalmente parafraseáveis em «ato de consagrar, reconhecer». Entretanto descobri que os franceses inventaram *anthume*, e já há por aí uns tantos *ântumos*.

Comment: @Jacinto como já deves saber não és obrigado a aceitar uma resposta, podes deixar a pergunta aberta até teres uma resposta satisfatória, e se isso não acontecer ficar sem visto para sempre. Fica só o comentário para ter a certeza que estás a par disso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sei disso, obrigado. Provavelmente, *em vida* é o melhor que há, a não ser que aceites o neologismo, pouco usado ainda, *ântumo*. Mas eu não usaria *em vida* em muitos contextos, como *conheci o filho em vida do João*. Daí a relutância.

Comment: Ainda bem que sabes. Olha que eu acho bem pertinente a outra resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Póstumo não oferece, em português, um antônimo específico. Basta verificar os dicionários especializados ou que apresentem tópicos de antonímia. Sob o pressuposto de que o verbete "póstumo" refira-se ao que se passa após a morte do indivíduo, seu antagônico semântico terá necessariamente de abordar o estado anterior à vida, tais como os vocábulos prematuro, imaturo, antenatal ou pré-natal, precedente e pregresso. Nesse aspecto, igualmente, não se pode admitir como antípoda de "póstumo" a menção a "memórias em vida", por implicar redundância resultante da constatação de que o exercício da memorização é atividade inerente à existência, na medida que o ato de memorizar ou registrar memórias só é possível no curso da vida. O que não se confunde com o ato de sua publicação ou difusão, possível "post mortem". Assim, salvo melhor juízo, contrapor-se-iam à expressão "memórias póstumas" as locuções, ou equivalentes, "memórias prematuras", "memórias imaturas", "memórias abortadas", "memórias antecedentes", "memórias fetais",  "memórias  anteconcepcionais (ou anticoncepcionais, conforme o caso)", memórias preexistentes", "memórias pré-natais" e por aí se vai.

Comment: Isto parece resposta de advogado: creio que fica claro logo no primeiro parágrafo da pergunta que com *antónimo de póstumo* eu quero dizer 'referente a antes da morte'. E tu foste o primeiro, aqui ou na minha pergunta [aqui no ELL](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298547/antonym-for-posthumous), a intepretar como 'referente a antes do nascimento'. E nem sequer é uma interpretação razoável, *Póstumo* é posterior ao momento em que a pessoa morreu; o antónimo é anterior a esse momento. Do mesmo modo o antónimo de pós-guerra não é pré-paz; e o antónimo de pós-casamento não é pré-divórcio

Answer (score -2):

*Ântumo*, por tradução do francês *anthume*.

Comment: Bem vindo Felix. Podes colocar alguma referência à esta palavra? Algum link de dicionário online, por exemplo?

Comment: Felix, secundando o @gmauch, a informação que dás na tua resposta já se encontrava nos comentários à pergunta e à outra resposta. Mas tu podes fazer disto uma boa resposta se incluíres links para demonstrar a existência de *anthume*, e até mesmo o uso de *ântumo* em português, que já se encontra também. Se buscares nos Google encontras ambos.