# Que palavra melhor exprime o conceito de "sem contrapartidas"?

Tags: expressões, palavra-para-ideia

Tenho tido dificuldade em explicar os dois diferentes significados de "incondicional": (1) sem condições prévias, e (2) sem obrigações -- isto é, contrapartidas que tenham que ser cumpridas posteriormente ao ato "incondicional".

O inglês não tem uma palavra específica, mas tem uma expressão que serve para o efeito: "no strings attached". Existirá algo semelhante (palavra ou expressão) em português?

O contexto onde pretendo usar a palavra é na descrição do [rendimento básico incondicional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renda_b%C3%A1sica_de_cidadania), que não tem condições prévias de elegibilidade além da cidadania (o que em inglês descreve-se como "[non means-tested](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/means-tested)") nem requer contrapartidas a quem recebe (em inglês, "[with no strings attached](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no_strings_attached)").

Uma forma de fazer esta distinção é usar "universal" para o primeiro significado, e "incondicional" para o segundo, mas o termo é ambíguo, e as pessoas frequentemente assumem que a incondicionalidade refere-se ao primeiro significado, e não ao segundo. Daí eu estar à procura de um termo ou expressão que possa passar essa noção de forma não ambígua.

Comment: Neste tipo de pergunta, o melhor é incluir exemplos do uso que queres dar à expressão; podias incluir uma frase ou duas com espaço em branco, em que nós teríamos que incluir a expressão desejada. Vê [aqui um exemplo do que eu tou a dizer](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1761/qual-%C3%A9-o-ant%C3%B3nimo-de-p%C3%B3stumo).

Comment: @Jacinto boa ideia, obrigado pela nota. Acrescentei mais contexto à pergunta e o exemplo específico de uso que pretendo dar a esta expressão.

Comment: Poderias dizer que o rendimento básico é concedido a todos sem exigência de nada em troca/de quaisquer contrapartidas. Possivelmente queres algo mais compacto. Se juntares à pergunta uma ou duas frases-exemplo com espaço em branco para a expressão desejada, fica mais claro o que procuras. *Incondicional* não me parece mal, especialmente em *rendimento universal incondicional*, porque o *universal* significa que é para todos, logo o *incondicional* será a outra coisa. Ou talvez fique mais claro *rendimento universal concedido incondicionalmente*.

Comment: Pois, eu estava à procura de algo compacto. Idealmente algo que pudesse substituir "incondicional" em Rendimento Básico _______", mas uma expressão curta que pudesse em poucas palavras transmitir o que o incondicional significa também seria bom :)

Comment: Sem pré-requisitos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um bom candidato para exprimir o conceito de “sem contrapartidas” é *sem compromisso*.

Em PT-BR, costuma-se utilizar esta expressão para indicar, especialmente no comércio, que certos serviços não serão cobrados. Por exemplo, algumas empresas oferecem “orçamentos sem compromisso”, ou seja, não exigem contrapartida ao avaliar o custo de um projeto.

O Linguee documenta [como vários tradutores optaram por traduzir a expressão *sem compromisso* ao inglês](http://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/traducao/sem+compromisso.html), e várias delas coincidem com o significado que você busca. Alguns exemplos que selecionei (ênfase minha):

- “Envie um trecho do vídeo para fazermos um orçamento **sem compromisso**” se traduz como “Send a little part of your video to us and we prepare a budget **without any obligation**”
- “uma oferta **sem compromisso** com a quantidade exacta” se traduz como “a **non-binding** price quotation with the exact number”

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão :) "sem compromisso" é uma boa forma de explicar sucintamente o significado de incondicional neste contexto. Se não surgir uma opção que possa substituir "incondicional" em "Rendimento Básico ______" (o que me parece ser o mais provável...) marco esta resposta como aceite.